# How to distribute Python package with Numba as optional dependency

Tags: python, packaging, numba

Given a numba-decorated code,

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f():
    ...
```

, how does one distribute this as a package with Numba as an optional dependency? For example, I want to install my package via `pip install mypackage[jit]` that includes numba and removing the extra tag excludes numba.

*A bad answer is one that requires user to install Numba and, for example, set `NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT=1`.*

Answer (score 4):

Create a dummy decorator:

```
try:
    from numba import jit
except ImportError:
    def jit(*args, **kwargs):
        return lambda f: f


@jit(nopython=True)
def f():
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution, albeit not pretty...

```
USE_NUMBA = True
try:
    from numba import jit
except ImportError:
    USE_NUMBA = False

def f():
    ...

if USE_NUMBA:
    f = jit(nopython=True)(f)
```